# How can I search for files by package in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Standard logging libraries output package.to.Class names for log events. Which is really useful for quickly navigating to the file context, however, by default, VSCode only seems to support searching for files using forward slashes / as the folder separator, which makes the terminal’s "click to search" feature feel a bit silly:

[image: Attempting to search by package name]

If there’s a setting or addon that makes VSCode recognize periods as folder separators within file search, it’d sure improve the debugging process.

Comment: That's a really good question